# How to check and disable several checkboxes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
...
<input type="checkbox" value="30" />
```

and the user has checked some of the boxes in a previous visit, and those values are stored in a variable (gets its value from the server):

```
myChoices = ["1", "5", "12"]
```

It is easy to check all checkboxes that have a value in myChoices, it can be done with:

```
$.(':checkbox').val(myChoices)
```

But I want to both check and disable these boxes. I do have a solution like follows:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function()
           {if ($.inArray(this.value, myChoices) != -1)
                {this.checked=true; this.disabled=true;}
})
```

It works fine, but I was simply wondering whether there is a simpler solution, something similar to val(), which is so elegant.

Thanks.

Comment: You say it works; it does not seem to: http://jsfiddle.net/6mfSX/

Comment: if you get the data from the server and the checkboxes get disabled, why don't you disable them on the server with php (or whatever you are using). could be easier but i dont know exactly how you use it :)

Comment: Following on @aleksv's suggestion, isn't a checked and disabled checkbox equal to `<input type="hidden" value="the_value"><span>the_value</span>`?

Comment: @Lajlek, Could you point to some documentation on passing arrays to `.val`?

Comment: @aleksv, I'm not generating HTML from the server. The HTML code is the same for everyone. Only when someone is logged in with their Facebook account, I use their credentials to make an AJAX call. That is, I use jQuery's AJAX call $.getJSON(), which returns a JSON array with the choices. And then, with the code I showed, I change the appearance of the HTML page in the client's browser.

Comment: @Shrikant, I think there is documentation for that on the jQuery website, http://api.jquery.com/val/. However, I am slowly reading this wonderful book from Manning, "jQuery in Action" and there is where I saw val() with parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$(":checkbox").val(myChoices).filter(":checked").attr("disabled",true);
```

Here is an example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P4VhK/

Comment: wohow! I never knew we could pass arrays to `.val`. Really good to know. Could you point me to some documentation on that kind of usage?

Comment: @Shrikant, to be honest, i have never done it before :D. I just improvised on Lejlek's code and applied the `disabled` attribute. So the credit goes to Lejlek or whoever he/she learnt from.

Comment: Wonderful! I love this solution. My problem was that val() was returned the whole wrapped set, and I didn't know how to disable only the checked boxes. Thank you!